# How to Align buttons in Java i try some of the ways but but not working in my code any clue what i do to solve this

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton

here is my code:

```
    bbtn = new JButton("Brightness");

    bbtn.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bbtn, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

    bbtn.setBorderPainted(false);

    bbtn.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    bbtn.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);

    bbtn.setBackground(Color.white);

    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Documents and Settings\\omi\\My Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplicationEditor\\src\\utilities_brightness.png");

    bbtn.setIcon(img);

    mpanel.add(bbtn);
```

`setAlignement` lines are not working i've also try the `setBounds` but still not working

Comment: It depands on Container Layout. Which alignment you want?

Comment: What do you mean by "align".  Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: whats reason to set LayoutManager to JButton, I can't see there something important for that

Comment: I'm making image editor and I want to set buttons on left site but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your JButton on a Container, and sets the layout manager of your container to feat the left alignment. This is a example maybe inspire you :

```
JPanel thePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
JButton theButton = new JButton("Britness");

thePanel.add(theButton);
```

Hope that helps, Salam

Comment: thnx buddy it works. how simple it was and how stupid i was :P

Comment: you are welcome, it's really simple you are not stupid just you have to practice =)